# Creating multiple plots with a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, plot, subset

My data is available [here](https://figshare.com/s/47bd7da8f18d954452b6), and looks like so:

```
sq_id        total_forays_day age_at_loc date.x  
  <chr>            <dbl>      <dbl>      <chr>   
22897                1         41        17-06-18
22897                1         42        17-06-19
22897                2         43        17-06-20
22897                2         43        17-06-20
22897                1         44        17-06-21
22897                1         45        17-06-22
```

I would like to make a `plot(total_forays_day~age_at_loc)` for 89 unique `sq_id` using a loop.

I can get unique plots by `sq_id` by running the following:

```
plot(total_forays_day~age_at_loc, data=(data%>%filter(sq_id=="22641")), type="l")
```

But that is not an efficient way to do it since I need to visualize 89 plots.

I have tried:

```
par(mfrow=c(10,10))
for(i in 1:1) { #loop over loop.vector
    plot(total_forays_day~age_at_loc[,i], data=data)
}
```

This does not work. I get the following error message:

> Error in age_at_loc[, i] : incorrect number of dimensions

How should I fix my `for` loop code? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you intend to do with these 89 plots? You might render them all to pdf using `pdf("quux.pdf")`/`plot(...)`/`dev.off()` or (even better) an rmarkdown document.

Comment: @r2evans I just need to visualize the plots to see if there is any weird trends in my data over time

Comment: Then what's wrong with the `for` loop? You can pause on each image within the loop by using `readline("next plot ...")` (press enter to continue) or `locator(1)` (click on the image). I don't know how to do "either <enter> or <click>", that'd be handy sometimes.

Comment: @r2evans I agree; a `for` loop is exactly what I should do. Problem is, the way I wrote my loop is giving me an error message. `Error in age_at_loc[, i] : incorrect number of dimensions`

Comment: If `age_at_loc` is a column, then you cannot use a comma in its indexing (it's just a vector). Try just `total_forays_day~age_at_loc[i]`.

Comment: @r2evans When I remove the comma (since `age_at_loc` is a column), it gives me a new error: `Error in (function (formula, data = NULL, subset = NULL, na.action = na.fail,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'age_at_loc[i]')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up front, try this:

```r
# remove [1:3] when you are comfortable with this and want to see all of them
for (d in split(data, data$sq_id)[1:3]) {
  plot(total_forays_day ~ age_at_loc, data=d)
  readline("next") # or locator(1)
}
```

Issues you encountered:

- `total_forays_day~age_at_loc[,i]` is treating `age_at_loc` like a frame, but it is a vector
- `total_forays_day~age_at_loc[i]` (as I incorrectly suggested) is comparing a vector against a single number, which does not work since `plot` expects all vectors to be the same length (`age_at_loc[i]` is length 1)

Your problem is that you are not splitting the data in an efficient manner. If you look at the results from `split(...)`, you'll see something like

```r
str(split(data, data$sq_id)[1:3])
# List of 3
#  $ 22640:'data.frame':    102 obs. of  4 variables:
#   ..$ sq_id           : int [1:102] 22640 22640 22640 22640 22640 22640 22640 22640 22640 22640 ...
#   ..$ total_forays_day: int [1:102] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#   ..$ age_at_loc      : int [1:102] 49 49 51 51 52 52 53 53 54 54 ...
#   ..$ date.x          : Factor w/ 124 levels "17-06-07","17-06-08",..: 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 ...
#  $ 22641:'data.frame':    52 obs. of  4 variables:
#   ..$ sq_id           : int [1:52] 22641 22641 22641 22641 22641 22641 22641 22641 22641 22641 ...
#   ..$ total_forays_day: int [1:52] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
#   ..$ age_at_loc      : int [1:52] 49 51 52 53 54 55 59 60 61 61 ...
#   ..$ date.x          : Factor w/ 124 levels "17-06-07","17-06-08",..: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 10 ...
#  $ 22653:'data.frame':    35 obs. of  4 variables:
#   ..$ sq_id           : int [1:35] 22653 22653 22653 22653 22653 22653 22653 22653 22653 22653 ...
#   ..$ total_forays_day: int [1:35] 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 ...
#   ..$ age_at_loc      : int [1:35] 58 58 59 59 60 61 61 62 63 63 ...
#   ..$ date.x          : Factor w/ 124 levels "17-06-07","17-06-08",..: 10 10 11 11 12 13 13 14 15 15 ...
```

Notice how each element of the list has identical `sq_id` in its frame. So `split(...)[[1]]` is a frame with 102 rows, all of them `sq_id` of `"22640"`. By iterating over that with `for (d in split(data, data$id))`, each pass in the loop has `d` assigned with one of these single-`sq_id` frames.

The use of `readlines("next")` versus `locator(1)` is purely subjective and user-experience. If you prefer to press enter, choose the first; if you prefer to click on the image, choose the second.

Know that if you are doing other things with the split data, it might be beneficial to split once and use many times, ala

```r
splitdata <- split(data, data$sq_id)
for (d in splitdata) { ... }
```

Comment: I appreciate you breaking that down for me. That explanation really helped clarify what my code was (and was not) doing.